# Override a property default value when referencing an existing schema

Tags: polymorphism, openapi

I'm trying to define query parameters that reference an existing schema but override it's default value, but this override seems to be ignored. Is it possible to do this?

For example, I have a reusable schema defined as

```yaml
PageNumber:
    type: integer
    example: 10
```

I have various endpoints that reference this schema as query parameters, however they each have their own default value; some endpoints default to 10, others default to 20, etc.

```yaml
/example/1:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: pageNumber
          in: query
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageNumber'
            default: 10
      responses:
        ...
/example/2:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: pageNumber
          in: query
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageNumber'
            default: 20
      responses:
        ...
```

The problem is that the `default` value seems to be ignored when a parameters schema references an existing schema.
[image]

However if I update the parameters no *not* reference the existing schema and instead define the schema inline, the default value is used:

```yaml
/example/1:
  get:
    parameters:
      - name: pageNumber
        in: query
        schema:
          type: number
          default: 10
```

[image]

Is it possible to override and apply this default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `allOf`

```yaml
paths:
  /example-1:
    get:
      tags:
        - stack
      summary:
      description:
      operationId:
      parameters:
        - name: pageNumber
          in: query
          schema: 
            allOf: 
              - $ref: "#/components/schemas/PageNumber"
              - default: 20
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
components:
  schemas:
    PageNumber:
      type: number
      example: 10
      default: 10
```

You can see the `example` still resolves from the component schema but the `default` value is overridden

[image: example with allOf to override property]

Comment: This works! I honestly could have sworn I tried this before raising this question but I must be mistaken. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped ya!  have a great day!